# Failing this.template.querySelector

Tags: lightning-web-components, locker-service, namespace

I have a component and am trying to retrieve an element from the template using `querySelector`, as follows:

```
const elt = this.template.querySelector('.thunder-ng');
```

But instead of returning the element, or null, it returns an odd object which only has an `toString` method defined, which yields this:

```
"SecureObject: [object HTMLDivElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }"
```

I traced way down inside `querySelector` and finally I could see where it was generating that weird object, but it was beyond me to figure out why. Here's the code where it ends up:

```
function SecureObject(thing, key) {
    let o = getFromCache(thing, key);
    if (o) {
      return o;
    }

    o = create(null, {
      toString: {
        value: function() {
          return `SecureObject: ${thing}{ key: ${JSON.stringify(key)} }`;
        },
      },
    });

    setRef(o, thing, key, true);
    addToCache(thing, o, key);
    registerProxy(o);

    return seal(o);
  }
```

One cannot do anything with this malformed stub object. It is not an actual element. The fact that it contains just an `toString` method is not an artifact of DevTools; that is really just what the object is. As such, of course any and all attempts to treat it like a DOM element, such as inserting DOM content using `appendChild` or `innerHTML`, fail.

```
const elt = this.template.querySelector('thunder-ng');
elt.appendChild(newChild); /// `undefined is not a function
```

The template is quite innocuous:

```
<template>
  <slot></slot>
  <div lwc:dom="manual" class="thunder-ng" role="application"></div>
</template>
```

Neither the `lwc:dom` nor the slots seem to make any difference. The problem persists.

The annoying thing is that this was working at some point in the past, and then suddenly stopped working, but of course I can't identify what I did to make it stop working.

I'm guessing this is some kind of namespace mismatch, but that's odd, because all my components are very much in the same namespace as far as I know.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you trying to modify the element? Did you try to set innerHTML but failed? What is the failure message?

Comment: Yes, as the `lwc:dom` might indicate, I'm trying to `appendChild` into that element. But I can't do that or `innerHTML` or anything else because it's not even an element. It's just an object with a single `toString` method.

Comment: @kamezaburo I guess you got the above object structure inside console.log, the dom element is secured when you log it on the console, so there should not be an issue with DOM manipulation.

Comment: @rahulgawale Actually, there is a problem, since what comes back from `querySelector` is not a DOM element in any sense of the word. It's just an object with a single `toString` method. `elt.appendChild` returns undefined, and `elt.appencChild(child)` of course tells me that `appendChild` is not a function.

Comment: @rahulgawale When I do `elt.appendChild` it says it's undefined. When I do `elt.appendChild()` it says `undefined is not a function`. I don't know how this could be considered "not an issue".

Comment: @kamezaburo I see, let me try this. can you add the code where you are trying to call append child.

Comment: @kamezaburo, were you able to figure this out?  I am running across this error as well

Comment: @willard I solved it, but I forgot how, sorry.

Comment: I figured it out.  It was a bit different from your use case, but basically, the code was being run when I dragged a sub-component (using js's draggable api).  The code was running in the sub-component's context, which didn't have access to the element referenced by querySelector.

Comment: @willard Thanks for sharing that with posterity. That could well have been what I was doing to--calling that in some kind of callback or event handler invoked by a lower-level component.

Comment: @kamezaburo facing same kind of issue, but In my case I'm trying to access `this.template.querySelector('c-child-component')` in parent component `renderedCallback()` function. Can you share your thoughts what could be the wrong.